# Check if bot has enough permissions (or handle it)

Tags: discord, discord.py

I'm looking for a way of handling a bot missing permissions. Like I remove it "send_messages" permission and I try to make it send a message.

Thing is i don't know how to do, I've been looking for this for hours, and i don't want to add a

```
if bot.has_permissions("send_messages"):
```

each time i want to do anything.
Also the purpose of this bot if to be on servers I am not on so editing guild's permissions is not an option.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a general error handler for the `Forbidden` error, which discord.py raises on a `403 Forbidden: Missing Permissions` error. You need to unpack it first from the general `CommandInvokeError` before.

```py
@bot.event
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.CommandInvokeError):
        error = error.original

    if isinstance(error, discord.errors.Forbidden):
        await ctx.send("Whatever you want to say here.")
```

Comment: Just tried it, it indeed passes by on_command_error(), but it just skips the isinstance(error, discord.Forbidden) and raises the error

Comment: @Frexom My bad, I have edited my code above and it should now work. I forgot you need to unpack the error from the general CommandInvokeError before you can listen for Forbidden errors.

Comment: Oh thanks! it works like a charm! I would never have found this alone, really thanks a lot!